# B2B, B2C Tenants in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a query with regards to Tenant Concept in Azure and its relation with B2B and B2C Tenants.
As per definition "Azure AD organises users and apps into group called tenants".
Here does App represent VMs, Storage Disk etc. in Resource Group?

Secondly, its mentioned that Subscription can only be associated with single AD Tenant at a time.
If so, how can B2B and B2C Users use the Resources under a subscription where B2B and B2C are managed as separate tenants?

Requesting you to clarify this concept.

Regards,
Vinoth K Balu

Answer (score 0):

An Azure subscription belongs to an Azure tenant (or organization). (This relationship was not intuitive to me at first, because you sign up for an Azure subscription and the "owning" Azure tenant is automatically created for you in the background.)

The admin credentials you create as part of the sign-up represent an Azure AD user (in your new tenant) and - as a global admin of the Azure tenant - that user can create resources in the subscription.

There are paid versions of Azure AD, but most people start with the free tier, so the resources (for example, VMs) in the subscription are what you pay for and the subscription is how you pay for it. If the same company had two projects and wanted to track the billing for the Azure costs separately, it could create a second subscription (under the original tenant) and create resources in the appropriate subscription to keep the billing as desired. (Billing issues are the only reason I can think of that you would create multiple subscriptions in the same tenant.)

The Azure AD user(s) can login to the Azure portal and create/manage the resources, but typically, if you create a Windows VM - you would use the resource (log into it via RDP) using a local Administrator account (just like a physical server), not your Azure AD user credentials.

Azure AD is not a cloud version of (on-premise) Active Directory. Due to the name, I think this is a common misconception.

Microsoft 365 (formerly Office 365) users are actually Azure AD users. Microsoft calls these "Work/School" accounts to differentiate between those and a (consumer) "Microsoft account". (The naming of these things adds to the complexity of discussing them.) With Windows 10, it's possible to join a computer to an Azure AD domain and login to the computer with your "Work/School" (actually Azure AD) user, but this is a different thing than logging in with an (on-premise) Active Directory account.

So (at least for now), most of the time you would use your Azure AD user credentials to login to the Azure portal and manage the resources, but will typically login to VMs with traditional credentials.

"App" as used here refers to an application (typically a web application) that is using Azure AD to authenticate with (similar to how you could use Okta or Google or Facebook as your identity provider).

A B2C tenant is really only used in this context. If your primary Azure AD tenant is  a directory of your company's users, and you have developed a web application - you could create a separate B2C tenant to hold that application's users. A B2C tenant wouldn't have a subscription or any resources (like VMs) - just users, groups, etc. for authenticating an application.

I'm not aware of their being a B2B "tenant". The B2B functionality lets you offer guest access to users in another Azure tenant/organization been given access to your tenant. Somewhat parallel to setting up a traditional AD domain trust.

Having said all of that, if you set up a VM and want to give RDP or SSH access to an end user - you can set that up in the VM and not worry about creating an Azure AD user. You could also run traditional Active Directory on Windows VMs running in Azure that are set up as domain controllers and give out traditional (not Azure) AD credentials.